# Using AntiCSRF with ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, csrf

I have installed the AntiCSRF HTTPModule but I need to use it with ajax . 
 
The token field name : RaiseException . 

 
CookieName : __CSRFCOOKIE . 
 
Should I send the token field value manually with ajax POST or there is something else to be done ? 
 
And since we use here a cookie, can't anyone create a cookie with the same name and the same value and send the value that appear in the hidden filed to the server and get the data or there is some restrictions about this ?!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the specific anti-CSRF module that you're using. There's anti-CSRF support built into ASP.Net, but it struggles with AJAX.

Most sites use a secured HTTP-only cookie for authentication. All the browsers support a *same origin policy* which means that only the site that creates a cookie can access it.

A CSRF attack works because that hacker doesn't need to see the cookies, as the user's browser will send them along with any request to your site. So the hacker creates a form that sends data to your site:

```
<form action="yoursite.com/userAdmin/Create">
    <input type="text" name="username" value="hackerUser" />
    <input type="text" name="rights" value="godlike" />
    ...
</form>
```

The hacker isn't an admin on your site, but they can trick a user who is into doing stuff for them.

Most anti CSRF protections work in the same way: by requiring the POST-ed form data to have an additional token that the site can access but that the hackers can't spoof.

So .Net's default implementation adds a cookie with a token, the same token in a hidden input, and then checks that they match. The hacker can't see the cookie, so can't reproduce the hidden input.

This is problem for AJAX calls for two reasons:

- .Net generates the token as a hidden input tag, meaning some Javascript is required to get that into the AJAX call.
- .Net's check against the token assumes that it's a form input, meaning that JSON calls pass it in the wrong format.

It sounds like what you need to do is manually add the value of your token's field name to the AJAX call, and make sure that you're sending form data.